# How to solve a jvm crash caused by jni functions ?

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, hid

I have a java application that dialogs with USB devices (msp430 processors).
The application sends and receive datas to them, it's done using hid communication, the java hid api.

Those jni calls make sometimes crash the JVM, generating a his_error_pid log :

```
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2e3be]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2e023]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x114ad]
C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x1016a]
C  [hidapi-jni-323265682556056020360.dll+0x19eb]
C  [hidapi-jni-323265682556056020360.dll+0x1f98]
j  com.codeminders.hidapi.HIDDevice.write([B)I+0
j  com.codeminders.hidapi.HIDManager.sendDataStatus([BLcom/codeminders/hidapi/HIDDevice;)I+90
```

How to fix that ?

I've tried updating the JRE, I had those errors before with the Texas instruments' dll, so I decided to use the java hid api since it's lower level than the Texas one...

Comment: Do you have access to the source of hidapi-jni DLL? If so, you could attach a debugger (I use Visual Studio) to the java process.

Comment: I do, but when I debug it using Visual studio, I have "First-chance exception at 0x77xxxxxxxxxx in myApplication : Access violation reading location 0xdXXXXXX"

Comment: No chance setting breakpoints anywhere? And there's a window in VS (don't know its English name) that shows which functions are currently on the stack. You did remember to run with a debug version of the DLL, I guess.

Comment: I loaded the java hid api solution, ran my program, attached the VS debugger to it and set breakpoints to the functions causing crashes. It never stops to breakpoints

Comment: Are you sure the program loads the debug DLL? Sometimes there's a release DLL lying around somewhere else and the program picking that one up (been there).